# How to access data in array in JSON

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

JSON:

```
{
"projects":[
{
"id":113,
"name":"Mobile app Android",
"description":"",
"created_on":"2014-10-03T16:53:56+02:00",
"updated_on":"2014-12-03T16:59:45+01:00"
},
{
"id":142,
"name":"Mobile app iOS",
"created_on":"2014-12-11T18:30:55+01:00",
"updated_on":"2014-12-11T18:30:55+01:00"
},
{
"id":52,
"name":"Test project",
"identifier":"grafikr",
"description":"",
"created_on":"2013-10-14T17:21:33+02:00",
"updated_on":"2014-10-10T17:40:47+02:00"
},
{
"id":37,
"name":"Sample project",
"identifier":"grafikf",
"description":"",
"created_on":"2013-09-18T16:31:25+02:00",
"updated_on":"2013-09-26T13:11:58+02:00"
}
],
"total_count":4,
"offset":0,
"limit":25
}
```

It is easy to access for example name of the first project (with name Mobile app Android) by **var name = json["projects"][0]["name"].stringValue**

But how do I access all names in SwiftyJSON? If I make a variable **var projects = json["projects"]**, it gives me:

```
[
  {
    "id" : 113,
    "created_on" : "2014-10-03T16:53:56+02:00",
    "name" : "Mobile app Android",
    "description" : "",
    "updated_on" : "2014-12-03T16:59:45+01:00"
  },
...
```

Now I don't have a problem with making a NSDictionary from data anymore, but this drives me crazy.

Comment: You don't need to cast with `as` like that. `ID` is already a String.

Comment: Also, stylistic convention would be to use camelCased variables, rather than UPPERCASE or snake_case. For `init`, try using `self.id = id` rather than `id = ID`.

Comment: One more thing—it should probably be `Project` (singular, not plural). To work with more than one project at a time, use an array of projects (`[Project]`).

Comment: @matt: id is a reserved word in Objective-C, meaning "pointer to any kind of Objective-C object". You should never, ever try to call a property or a variable "id".

Comment: @gnasher729 With all due respect, I know what `id` is. This is Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: @gnasher729 It's not my job, it's my hobby and my project is done. Nobody is perfect and after one week of iOS programming it wasn't such as dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on in your code sample—perhaps too much to be addressed by a single Stack Overflow question / answer.

I would strongly recommend going back to Apple's resources for Swift and iOS application patterns. Topics to revisit would include synchronous versus asynchronous programming, authentication, and using data sources with table views.

Comment: I've modified my answer, please look at those changes.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work. Your json also contains "total_count", which looking at it, I assume that's the count of the number of projects. Pull that count out, loop over till the count and fetch the name.

```
 var names = [String]()
 let count = json["total_count"].int
 for index in 0..<count {
      let name = json["projects"][index]["name"].string
      names.append(name)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **`SwiftyJSON`** the **`Swifty`** way???

Try this:

```
let names = json["projects"].arrayValue.map {
    $0["name"].stringValue
}
```